# prevent VC++ DLL rebasing by PE header editing

Tags: visual-c++, dll, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I need to set the flag /FIXED to prevent the rebasing of my VC++ dll without recompiling. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w368ysh2.aspx). 
Where is this flag in the PE header?

thank you,
Riccardo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [/FIXED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w368ysh2.aspx) linker switch does not correspond to a flag in the PE header, it actually specifies whether a relocation section is added to the PE file by the linker.

The [`DYNAMIC_BASE`](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=100) flag [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784537/3501) talks about specifies whether the OS is allowed to relocate the image in memory when it is loaded (if ASLR is on).

- Linking with /FIXED is fine for a .exe as long as you don't need ASLR for securiy (Web browser etc)
- Linking with /FIXED for a .dll is **not** a good idea, if the dll cannot be loaded at its preferred address (some other dll might already be loaded there) the dll loading will fail!